# Use Spark when function without otherwise but keep column values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I frequently find myself replacing values in columns using

```
when($"myCol".isNull,myCrazyFunction).otherwise($"myCol")
```

To me the `.otherwise($"myCol")` feels kind of redundant.

Is there a better way to replace some values under some condition and otherwise just leave everything as it is without using the otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [`coalesce()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#coalesce) for that.

```
select(coalesce($"myCol", myCrazyFunction))
```

Just remember that `myCrazyFunction` should return a `Column` type.